# quotes in prepopulated html fields

Tags: javascript, html

If you want to prepopulate an html text field with a string that includes a double quote ("),
you need to html-encode it, as &quot; , unfortunately, the string '"abc"' encoded as "&quot;abc&quot;" submitted with the form to the server, is indistinguishable by the server from the string "&quot;abc&quot;" entered literally.

Using ' to delimit the text field value attribute is not an available option, since the input field is being populated from javascript.  Escaping the " with \ or \ \ does not work (Firefox); Javascript allows that escaping, but the html renderer just sees the \ and the " as distinct.

Is there a workaround for including " in prepopulated html fields, while allowing the input of raw strings that match html entity names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `"abc"` into a textbox, it will be submitted to the server as `%22abc%22` (but whatever language/framework you're using should transparently decode it back to `"abc"`).

If you want to pre-populate a textbox with `"abc"` then you'd use `&quot;abc&quot;` for the `value` attribute. This will also be submitted to the server as `%22abc%22`.

If you type `&quot;abc&quot;` into a textbox, it will be submitted to the server as `%26quot%3Babc%26quot%3B` (but whatever language/framework you're using should transparently decode it back to `&quot;abc&quot;`).

If you want to pre-populate a textbox with `&quot;abc&quot;` then you'd use `&amp;quot;abc&amp;quot;` for the `value` attribute. This will also be submitted to the server as `%26quot%3Babc%26quot%3B`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the string `"&quot;Hello World&quot;"` and you want to place it into a HTML text input. To do this, you'll need to escape all the HTML entities. It would look like this:

`<input type="text" value="&quot;&amp;quot;Hello World&amp;quot;&quot;" />`

When submitted, the server-side will get the string `"&quot;Hello World&quot;"`